# Visualizing an elevation map in RVIZ

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, rviz, visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I currently have an aerial image of a large terrain and its elevation map, which gives the height of every pixel in the image. I would like to know if there is a way in RVIZ to visualize the image in 3D using the data from the elevation map. The 3D visualization could be such that the original 2D image is seen when one looks at it top-down and the remaining portions (for instance, the side faces of buildings in the image) just have some interpolated values. It would be great if someone can suggest a way to do this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11601/visualizing-an-elevation-map-in-rviz/) by [venkat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1246/venkat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2011-10-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alternatively you could use Blender to create a mesh from the elevation map (see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Making_Landscapes_with_heightmaps)) and export that with the Blender->Ogre exporter. That way you should be able to load that into rviz.

---

Originally posted by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) with karma: 261 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-10-20**:
This seems like a better solution.